# Displaying an Array, sorting with pointers, then displaying the original again in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I'm trying to display an array, make a copy of that array and copy the pointers, then sort the pointer array, then display the original array in the original order.
What am I doing wrong? I've been working on this for an entire day. The output looks like.

```
Now displaying data in original order:
47 48 58 123 456 789 188 0 3000 47 939 
2373 1873 283 948 333 283 2835 248 444 555 
732 1983 473 939 3000 7 9 2496 1729 1776 
11 12 84 126 120  

Now displaying data in sorted order:
0 7 9 11 12 47 47 48 58 84 120 
123 126 188 248 283 283 333 444 456 473 
555 732 789 939 939 948 1729 1776 1873 1983 
2373 2496 2835 3000 3000  

Now displaying data in original order:
0 7 9 11 12 47 47 48 58 84 120 
123 126 188 248 283 283 333 444 456 473 
555 732 789 939 939 948 1729 1776 1873 1983 
2373 2496 2835 3000 3000
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bubblesort(int *arr,int n);
void display(int array[],int);
void ptrdisplay(int array[],int size);
void swap(int *x, int *y);

int main()
{
    int data[]={47,48,58,123,456,789,188,0,3000,47,939,2373,1873,283,948,333,283,2835,248,444,555,732,1983,473,939,3000,7,9,2496,1729,1776,11,12,84,126,120};
    int size= sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
    printf("Now displaying data in original order\n");
    display(data,size);

    int * ptrdata[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        ptrdata[i]=&data[i];
    }

    bubblesort(*ptrdata, size);

    printf("\nNow displaying data in sorted order\n");
    ptrdisplay(*ptrdata, size);

    printf("\nNow displaying data in original order\n");
    display(data,size);

}

void display(int array[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
        if(i==10||i==20||i==30)
            printf("\n");
    }

    puts(" ");
}


void ptrdisplay(int array[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
        if(i==10||i==20||i==30)
            printf("\n");
    }

    puts(" ");
}

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x   = *y;
    *y   = temp;
}


int bubblesort(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
        for(j=0;j<(n-1-i);j++)
        {
            if(*(arr+j)>*(arr+(j+1)))
            {
                swap((arr+j), (arr+(j+1)));
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `int bubblesort(int *arr[], int n)` and `void ptrdisplay(int *array[], int size)`

Comment: I get a very large error, like XCode kicks me out of the sourcecode.

Comment: Your swap function is swapping the actual array's elements, not the pointer array's.

Comment: Im passing ptrarray into the function though, how is it the actual array?

Comment: That's the thing. You aren't. You're passing *ptrdata. That's effectively passing ptrdata[0], which points to the first element of the original array.

Comment: [example](http://ideone.com/HfmRT2)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version of your code that does what you want, and I'll explain what the changes are and why as comments in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int array[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
        if(i==10||i==20||i==30)
            printf("\n");
    }
    puts(" ");
}

// changed from int to int*, since you're passing an array of pointers
void ptrdisplay(int* array[],int size) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        printf("%d ",*array[i]);
        if(i==10||i==20||i==30)
            printf("\n");
    }
        puts(" ");
}

// changed from swap(int* x, int* y) since you want to sort your pointers, not the values in them
void swap(int **x, int **y)
{
    int* temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x   = *y;
    *y   = temp;
}

int bubblesort(int *arr[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
        for(j=0;j<(n-1-i);j++)
        {
            if(*arr[j] > *arr[j+1]) // *(arr + (j + 1)) and arr[j + 1] are the same but the latter is more readable
            {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); // here, pass the address of the pointers to be sorted, so you're basically passing by reference, not value.
            }
        }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int data[]={47,48,58,123,456,789,188,0,3000,47,939,2373,1873,283,948,333,283,2835,248,444,555,732,1983,473,939,3000,7,9,2496,1729,1776,11,12,84,126,120};
    int size= sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
    printf("Now displaying data in original order\n");
    display(data,size);

    int * ptrdata[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        ptrdata[i]=&data[i];
    }

    bubblesort(ptrdata, size); // changed from *ptrdata, pass the address of the array, not the value (that's what *ptrdata does)

    printf("\nNow displaying data in sorted order\n");
    ptrdisplay(ptrdata, size); // same as with the bubblesort call

    printf("\nNow displaying data in original order\n");
    display(data,size);
}
```

Note the changes made to the sort function, the swap function, the display function, and the way these are called. 
Basically, when sorting based on pointers, you'd need to deal with one extra level of indirection.

You know that with integer arrays, you pass the address of the elements to the swap function. With pointers, it's the same thing, except you need to deal with an extra `*`.

Comment: Added comments to the code wherever changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code,

> ptrdata[i]=&data[i];

this means **ptrdata** will hold the address of **data**.

Any operation on **ptrdata** will be done on memory location, which it is referring to,same as **data**.

So if you sort the ptrdata, it will sort data as well.

This is the reason why you are not getting original data values.

You can copy data array into another array and later use it to display original unsorted values, this is just a quick fix, may not be best practice.

Comment: What would I change then?

Comment: @JoeCoder Look at my answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function sorts an array of `int`, not an array of `int *`.  When you call it, you're not passing your pointer array, but its first element -- and that first element is a pointer to the first element in your `int` array, and has the same value as the pointer that your original `int` array would decay to if you'd passed *that*.